# How do you log an objects details to the test console with `cy.log`?

Tags: cypress

When you do something like the following:

```
const someObject = {
    key: 1,
    anotherKey: 'test'
}
cy.log("Some object", someObject)
```

It will be rendered in the Cypress UI as `Some object, Object{2}`

Is there a way to get this to print prettier?

I am on version `10.3.0` here is a result with my actual log message:
[image]

Actual code:

```
        const loginInput = {
          userContext: "global_",
          email: finalEmail,
          password,
          verificationCode,
        };

        cy.log("Authenticating via GraphQL with the following details", loginInput);
```

Comment: How can my question be a duplicate of a question that is younger than mine? Lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran the same code, and it is showing the key-value pairs in the log.

[image: test runner screenshot]

You can use the Javascript Method `Object.entries()` to loop over the key-value pair and log them one by one.

```js
const someObject = {
  key: 1,
  anotherKey: 'test',
  anotherKey2: 'test2',
}
Object.entries(someObject).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  cy.log(key, value)
})
```

[image: Test runner 2]

Comment: What version are you using? I am on `10.3.0`

Comment: I am using `10.4.0`.

Comment: Ok, I will try and bump and see if that resolves it!

Comment: Nope, that didn't work for me... what browser were you using above?

Comment: I think you have to write the code you are actually trying because your screneshot and your code are different. This should work in 10.3.0 as well

Comment: Shared it above, the actual code is as simple as the example. There does seem to be a difference though as if I hardcode the example object it DOES log correctly.

Comment: Ah, I guess if an object has greater than 2 keys it prints it the object way instead of as a string. Pretty arbitrary.

Comment: Yes that is pretty weird actually as I could reproduce this behavior. Anyways I have updated the answer, you can check it out if that works.

Comment: I also considered converting the object to a string, but I still want the entire object to show in browser console log.